# Can't arrange scraped content in some customized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the `car`, `model` and `load` from [this webpage](https://www.fjordsen.com/en-eu/vehicles/). The script I've written can parse them flawlessly. However, what I can't do is arrange them in a customized manner.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.fjordsen.com/en-eu/vehicles/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".card-default"):
    item_title = items.select_one("h4.card-title > a").get_text(strip=True)
    item_content = [item.text for item in items.select("td")[2:]]
    print(item_title,item_content)
```

Output the script produces at this moment:

```
Audi ['A1', '75kg✓', 'A3', '75kg✓', 'A4', '90kg✓', 'A5', '90kg✓', 'A6', '100kg✓', 'A7', '100kg✓', 'A8', '100kg✓', 'Q2', '75kg✓', 'Q3', '75kg✓', 'Q5', '75kg✓', 'Q7', '75kg✓', 'Q8', '100kg✓']
BMW ['1Serie', '75kg✓', '2SerieActiveTourer', '75kg✓', '2SerieCabrio', '0kg', '2SerieCoupe', '75kg✓', '2SerieGrandCoupe', '75kg✓', '2SerieGrandTourer', '75kg✓', '3Serie', '75kg✓', '3SerieGranTurismo', '75kg✓', '3SerieTouring', '75kg✓', '4SerieCabrio', '0kg', '4SerieCoupe', '75kg✓', '4SerieGranCoupe', '75kg✓', '5Serie', '100kg✓', '5SerieTouring', '100kg✓', '6SerieGranTurismo', '100kg✓', '7Serie', '100kg✓', '8Serie', '75kg✓', '8SerieCabrio', '0kg', '8SerieGranCoupe', '75kg✓', 'i3', 'Checkinstructionmanualforyourcar', 'i8', 'Checkinstructionmanualforyourcar', 'i8Roadster', 'Checkinstructionmanualforyourcar', 'X1', '75kg✓', 'X2', '75kg✓', 'X3', '100kg✓', 'X4', '100kg✓', 'X5', '100kg✓', 'X6', '100kg✓', 'X7', '100kg✓', 'Z4', 'Checkinstructionmanualforyourcar']
```

Output I wish to get (showing first few):

```
Audi A1 75kg
Audi A3 75kg
Audi A4 90kg
Audi A5 90kg
Audi A6 100kg
```

How can I make the script produce the output similar to the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in `zip()` function.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.fjordsen.com/en-eu/vehicles/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".card-default"):
    item_title = items.select_one("h4.card-title > a").get_text(strip=True)
    item_content = [item.text for item in items.select("td")[2:]]
    for t, w in zip(item_content[::2], item_content[1::2]):
        print(item_title, t, w)  # or print(item_title, t, w.split()[0]) without the `✓` sign
```

Prints:

```
Audi A1 75kg  ✓
Audi A3 75kg  ✓
Audi A4 90kg  ✓
Audi A5 90kg  ✓
Audi A6 100kg  ✓
Audi A7 100kg  ✓
Audi A8 100kg  ✓
Audi Q2 75kg  ✓
Audi Q3 75kg  ✓
Audi Q5 75kg  ✓
Audi Q7 75kg  ✓
Audi Q8 100kg  ✓
BMW 1 Serie 75kg  ✓
BMW 2 Serie Active Tourer 75kg  ✓
BMW 2 Serie Cabrio 0kg
BMW 2 Serie Coupe 75kg  ✓
BMW 2 Serie Grand Coupe 75kg  ✓

...and so on.
```

Edit by uwtd tv:

```
item_content[::2] = starts on index 0 and take 2 jumps to next model

item_content[1::2] = starts in index 1 and take 2 jumps to next load
```

Comment: A little clarity on how `[::2]` and  `[1::2]` work or any link where they have been described will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @SMTH https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/

Comment: I have edited the post with

item_content[::2] = starts on index 0 and take 2 jumps to next model

item_content[1::2] = starts in index 1 and take 2 jumps to next load

But the edit have to be  approved by trusted community members

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of achieving the same output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.fjordsen.com/en-eu/vehicles/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".card-default"):
    item_title = items.select_one("h4.card-title > a").get_text(strip=True)
    for elem in items.select("tr"):
        model,weight = [item.text for item in elem.select("td")]
        print(item_title,model,weight)
```

Output are like:

```
Audi Model Maximum roof load while driving
Audi A1 75kg  ✓
Audi A3 75kg  ✓
Audi A4 90kg  ✓
Audi A5 90kg  ✓
Audi A6 100kg  ✓
Audi A7 100kg  ✓
Audi A8 100kg  ✓
Audi Q2 75kg  ✓
Audi Q3 75kg  ✓
Audi Q5 75kg  ✓
Audi Q7 75kg  ✓
Audi Q8 100kg  ✓
BMW Model Maximum roof load
BMW 1 Serie 75kg  ✓
BMW 2 Serie Active Tourer 75kg  ✓
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got two good answers but if you want to run your code with small fixes try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
allcars = []
r = requests.get("https://www.fjordsen.com/en-eu/vehicles/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select(".card-default"):
    item_title = items.select_one("h4.card-title > a").get_text(strip=True)
    item_content = [item.text for item in items.select("td")[2:]]
    cars = ([f'{str(item_title)} {m} {l.split(" ")[0]} ' for m, l in zip(item_content[0::2], item_content[1::2])])
    allcars.append(cars)
    for car in cars:
        print(car)
```

output:

```
Audi A1 75kg 
Audi A3 75kg 
Audi A4 90kg 
Audi A5 90kg 
Audi A6 100kg 
Audi A7 100kg 
Audi A8 100kg 
Audi Q2 75kg 
Audi Q3 75kg 
Audi Q5 75kg...
```

This code makes two lists **allcars** and an other **cars** and loops through cars. allcars contains a list of lists of car manufacturers, mode and load:

```
[['Audi A1 75kg ', 'Audi A3 75kg ', 'Audi A4 90kg ', 'Audi A5 90kg ', 'Audi A6 100kg ', 'Audi A7 100kg ', 'Audi A8 100kg ', 'Audi Q2 75kg ', 'Audi Q3 75kg ', 'Audi Q5 75kg ', 'Audi Q7 75kg ', 'Audi Q8 100kg '], ['BMW 1 Serie 75kg ', 'BMW 2 Serie Active Tourer 75kg ', 'BMW 2 Serie Cabrio 0kg....
```

Comment: Using your solution I get only the first item of each list.

Comment: Now i have edited my code so it fits your wish.. It is almost the same code as Andrej Kesely but a bit different